# Integrate returns "diverging integral" for obviously convergent expression

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, bugs, warning-messages

**Bug introduced in 13.0 or earlier. Fixed in 13.2.0 or earlier.**

---

`Integrate[Cos[phi]^2*Sin[phi]^n, {phi, 0, Pi}, Assumptions -> n > 0]`
on Mathematica 13.0 returns the obviously mistaken error message (`Integrate::idiv`):

[image]

Curiously enough, just replacing $n$ by $n-2$,
`Integrate[Cos[phi]^2*Sin[phi]^(n-2), {phi, 0, Pi},  Assumptions -> n > 2]`
returns the correct answer
$\frac{\sqrt{\pi }\, \Gamma \left(\frac{n-1}{2}\right)}{2 \Gamma \left(\frac{n}{2}+1\right)}.$

Any idea what is going on?

---

*Thank you for the workarounds. Still, I would be interested to know why this fails, is there a lesson here, is it a more general difficulty? The integrand seems so simple and well-behaved, why does Mathematica think it "does not converge"?*

Comment: The first integral does not evaluate and has no error message for me in V13.0 (Mac M1). (The second does the same as shown above.) -- This works for me, I think: `Integrate[Cos[phi]^2*Sin[phi]^n // TrigToExp, {phi, 0, Pi}, Assumptions -> n > 0]`

Comment: I think this is a bug and should be reported to "support@wolfram.com"

Comment: @MichaelE2: Your workaround does work, but its output `(\[Pi]^(3/2) Sec[(n \[Pi])/2])/(2 Gamma[1/2 - n/2] Gamma[2 + n/2])` is not convenient (say for $n=1$).

Comment: A couple more dissatisfying workarounds: `Integrate[Cos[phi]^2*Sin[phi]^n, {phi, 0, Pi}, GenerateConditions -> False] // FullSimplify[#, n < -4] &`
and
`Normal@Integrate[#, {phi, 0, Pi}] & /@ Expand[(1 - Sin[phi]^2) Sin[phi]^n] // FullSimplify`

Comment: The antiderivative for general $n$ is not that simple. It seems there is a problem for MA at $\phi=\pi/4$ (my answer below), but I doubt you can learn anything useful from it.

Comment: Sorry for a mistake: someone turned of my `Integrate::idiv` message. I didn't do it, so I must have aborted something when it had been internally turned off. Anyway, it misled me, as did no one else contradicting me.  After turning it on, I now get the same error as you.

Comment: Reported as a bug

Answer (score 5):

I suggest a workaround

```
f[n_] = Integrate[Sin[phi]^n, {phi, 0, Pi}, Assumptions -> n > 0]
FullSimplify[f[n] - f[n + 2]]
```

$$\frac{\sqrt{\pi } \Gamma \left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)}{2 \Gamma \left(\frac{n}{2}+2\right)}$$

Another way of calculating the integral

```
FullSimplify[
 Integrate[Cos[phi]^2*Sin[phi]^n, {phi, 0, Pi/4, Pi}, 
  Assumptions -> n > 0]]
```

suggests that in MA way of integrating the antiderivative has a singularity at $\phi=\pi/4$. Have no idea why.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a way to get the answer by changing the integral by symmetry. Powers of sine and cosine that depend on parameters have always been tricky for `Integrate`.  Not sure why the trick below works and the original fails.

```
Integrate[
 Cos[phi]^2*Sin[phi]^n + Sin[phi]^2*Cos[phi]^n, {phi, 0, Pi/2}, 
 Assumptions -> n > 0]
(*  (Sqrt[π] Gamma[(1 + n)/2])/(2 Gamma[2 + n/2])  *)
```

*Workarounds from my comments:*

Both

```
Integrate[Cos[phi]^2*Sin[phi]^n, {phi, 0, Pi}, 
  GenerateConditions -> False] // FullSimplify[#, n < -4] &

Normal@Integrate[#, {phi, 0, Pi}] & /@ 
  Expand[(1 - Sin[phi]^2) Sin[phi]^n] // FullSimplify
```

give

```
(*  (Sqrt[π] Gamma[(1 + n)/2])/(2 Gamma[2 + n/2])  *)
```

but not in a satisfying way.

And

```
Integrate[Cos[phi]^2*Sin[phi]^n // TrigToExp, {phi, 0, Pi}, Assumptions -> n > 0]
```

gives

```
(*  (π^(3/2) Sec[(n π)/2])/(2 Gamma[1/2 - n/2] Gamma[2 + n/2])  *)
```

which you have to use `Limit` to evaluate at odd integers.  Or we can expand secant and gamma according to their infinite products to get the first result above:

```
(π^(3/2) Sec[(n π)/2])/(2 Gamma[1/2 - n/2] Gamma[2 + n/2]) /. 
  Sec[(n π)/2]/Gamma[1/2 - n/2] -> 1/(Pi ((π - n Pi)/(2 π))*
    Product[
     (1 - (π - n π)^2 /
      (4 k^2 π^2)) ((1 + 1/k)^(1/2 (-1 - n))/(1 + (-1 - n)/(2 k))),
     {k, Infinity}]) // FullSimplify
```

---

*Update:*

`Integrate` tries a substitution $\phi = \arctan(p/2)$, which fails for reasons I don't understand, since the transformed integral, while improper, converges:

```
Cos[phi]^2*Sin[phi]^n*Dt[phi, p] /. phi -> ArcTan[p/2] /. 
   t : _Sin | _Cos :> TrigExpand[t] /. p -> phi // Simplify
Integrate[2 %, {phi, 0, \[Infinity]}, Assumptions -> n > 0]
(*
  (8 (phi/Sqrt[4 + phi^2])^n)/(4 + phi^2)^2
  (Sqrt[\[Pi]] Gamma[(1 + n)/2])/(2 Gamma[2 + n/2])  
*)
```

My guess is that there's a simple(?) bug that is not particularly interesting, but maybe someone else will have more insight. `Integrate` can generate answers to equivalent integrals involving things like `Hypergeometric2F1[2, 1/2 + n/2, 3/2, 1]`, which is undefined for `n>0`.  It evaluates to `ComplexInfinity` if `n` is given a definite, nonnegative value. I do not know if that is connected to the `idiv` divergence error.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to work:

```
res = Integrate[Cos[phi]^m*Sin[phi]^n, {phi, 0, \[Pi]}] /. m -> 2


N[Table[{NIntegrate[Cos[phi]^2*Sin[phi]^n, {phi, 0, Pi}], 
  res}, {n, 1, 6}]]

(* {{0.666667, 0.666667}, {0.392699, 0.392699}, {0.266667, 
 0.266667}, {0.19635, 0.19635}, {0.152381, 0.152381}, {0.122718, 0.122718}} *)
```

Comment: true, but it does not give the symbolic answer for any $n$, does it?

Comment: @CarloBeenakker I obtained a symbolic answer for `res` that claims to be valid for any $n$ with a real part greater than $-1$. (Output: `ConditionalExpression[(Sqrt[\[Pi]] Gamma[(1 + n)/2])/(2 Gamma[(4 + n)/2]), Re[n] > -1]`)  Is it the condition (so that it is not valid for ***any*** $n$) or did you get something else?

Comment: apologies, I had not understood that from the answer; so somehow "Integrate[Cos[phi]^m*Sin[phi]^n, {phi, 0, \[Pi]}]" works but "Integrate[Cos[phi]^2*Sin[phi]^n, {phi, 0, \[Pi]}]" fails; no idea why, but at least this is a way to work around the bug.

Answer (score 3):

Two small steps are better than one big step. A simple workaround in 13.0.0 on Windows 10 is as follows.

```
Integrate[1/2*Cos[2*phi]*Sin[phi]^n, {phi, 0, Pi},  Assumptions -> n > 0] + 
Integrate[1/2*Sin[phi]^n, {phi, 0, Pi}, Assumptions -> n > 0]
```

> `(Sqrt[\[Pi]] Gamma[(1 + n)/2])/(2 Gamma[1 + n/2]) - ( n Sqrt[\[Pi]] Gamma[(1 + n)/2])/(4 Gamma[2 + n/2])`

```
FullSimplify[%]
```

> `(Sqrt[\[Pi]] Gamma[(1 + n)/2])/(2 Gamma[2 + n/2])`

Addition. Concerning possible explanation of the incorrect result, I share @MichaelE2's opinion since

```
Integrate[Cos[phi]^2*Sin[phi]^n, phi, Assumptions -> n > 0]
```

> `(1/(1 + n))Sqrt[Cos[phi]^2] Hypergeometric2F1[-(1/2), (1 + n)/2, (3 + n)/2, Sin[phi]^2] Sec[ phi] Sin[phi]^(1 + n)`

```
Plot3D[%, {phi, 0, Pi}, {n, 0, 3}]
```

[image]